# CMake stripping static library

Tags: linux, cmake, static-libraries

I'm using CMake 2.8 and having an problem when I issue a 'make
install/strip'.  My project includes two libraries: one static and one
shared. The shared library gets properly stripped, but the static one does
not.  Do I need to specify a special parameter to get the static library to
be stripped or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks for the help!

OS: Ubuntu 10.10

Compiler: g++ 4.4.5

Update:  I found what I really wanted was the "strip --strip-unneeded" option.  I'm not sure why CMake doesn't do that by default since it is closer to stripped than not doing anything, but I was able to work around with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is problem with difference beetween static and shared librarys

- Shared is machine code with some headers
- Static is compressed .o files

So the stripper cannot access code of static library, but I think on the time of compilation (linking) with static library the executable will be stripped.